# Severity Code Description Project A field in the dataset ‘DataSet1’ has the name ‘[Date_&_Time]’. Field names must be CLS-compliant identifiers

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I got this error when building the solution. i put replaced to underscore from blank space but it is still not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try replacing the ampersand (`&`)? In code, usually only characters like A-Z, 0-9 and \_ are allowed in names (in some cases more, in some cases less).

Comment: i have not try, but (&) is included in my field name in my database.

Comment: Using spaces and other special characters in database table or column names is just a bad idea.  Are you able to change the column name in the database?  If so, do so.  If no other name is more appropriate, us `DateAndTime`.

Comment: The issue is most likely not the database column name per se but that the `DataColumn` in your typed `DataSet` is named after it directly and that's a bad name in VB.  In that case, you should be able to open your `DataSet` in the designer, select that column, open the Properties window and then edit the name of the `DataColumn` directly, setting it to something more suitable.